# How to extract colors from ColorsNear?

Tags: color, sampling

Is there any way to get a discrete list of samples from the [`ColorsNear`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorsNear.html) function?
I have tried

```
ColorsNear[hexToRGB["#9581FD"], .5, ColorDistance -> "CIE2000"] // 
 Subdivide[8]
```

where

```
hexToRGB = 
  RGBColor @@ (IntegerDigits[#~StringDrop~1~FromDigits~16, 256, 3]/
      255.) &;
```

But it doesn't return anything meaningful.

I'm guessing what is being returned is some sort of gradient object (idk new to mathematica)
but it still seems plausable to take samples from this.

Just want to add to *creidhne*'s answer that to get a list of nearest colors in order I use the following

```
cp = ChromaticityPlot3D[
  ColorsNear[RGBColor["#9981df"], .1, "CIE2000"], "LAB", 
  PlotRange -> All]
R = DiscretizeGraphics[cp]
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Tiny], Point[RandomPoint[R, 5000]]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
c = LABColor /@ RandomPoint[R, 50];
t = FindShortestTour[c, 
    DistanceFunction -> (ColorDistance[#1, #2, 
        DistanceFunction -> "CIE2000"] &)][[2]];
c[[t]]
Nearest[c, RGBColor["#72a1d8"], 10, 
 DistanceFunction -> (ColorDistance[#1, #2, 
     DistanceFunction -> "CIE2000"] &)]
```

Comment: ColorsNear returns a central color and a "ball" or radius about that central color. So you shouldn't expect a discrete list (it's more like a region). What you are trying to do?

Comment: right, so could I take a slice of the sphere, and extract a set of colors on the perimeter? Essentially I want a look at what colors are available at a fixed distance away from another color. I realize we are talking about a 3d object but foremost I want the farthest points(the points along the perimeter a radius r away) but if I could get the gradient out to that radius and extract from that would be ideal. Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: Presumably I could then tweak L, a, b to find better a better look at the colors I am looking for.

Comment: If you have some way of manipulating the "ball" that would suffice. I could then maybe look at taking a directional derivative or something to work with it to find properties of interest such as the fastest direction towards saturation, or w/e. The examples wolfram gives don't give alot to work with.

Comment: ColorsNear is giving you the ball, which varies depending on color space (LAB, RGB, etc). If you want to look at the ball, check out the second example under "Basic Examples" in the help file. It shows you how to look at the ball.

Comment: Note that `RGBColor["#9581FD"]` is valid syntax: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RGBColor.html#1177527921

Comment: @bills right I have a 3d view in LAB from 2nd example but how can I extract a discrete color on/in the ball? I realize I can take the coordinates from the graph but I would like finer grain control than just what I can approximate by looking at graph

Comment: @ChipHurst great! was not aware of that. thanks.

Comment: by approx I mean I don't want to have to line my fingers up on the picture to find the LAB values. Is there no way so sample discrete values from ColorsNear?

Comment: @skyfire - I don't know of a built-in way to do this. You should file a suggestion (go to Help->Give Feedback in the menu) that you would like to be able to sample colors using ColorsNear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChromaticityPlot3D` makes a graphic display of the region that's returned by `ColorsNear`. In the LAB color space, the region is clipped because the distance, 0.5, includes a large gamut of colors.

```
ChromaticityPlot3D[ColorsNear[RGBColor["#9581FD"],0.5,"CIE2000"],"LAB",PlotRange->All]
```

[image: 3D gamut of the color space showing clipping]

So, let's choose a smaller distance and use its more manageable region.

```
cp=ChromaticityPlot3D[ColorsNear[RGBColor["#9581FD"],0.2,"CIE2000"],"LAB",PlotRange->All]
```

[image: 3D gamut of the color space with smaller distance]

Use `DiscretizeGraphics` to convert the graphics object to a `MeshRegion`. Because `ChromaticityPlot3D` used the LAB color space to display the `ColorsNear` region, points from the region are LAB colors.

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = DiscretizeGraphics[cp];
```

This graphic shows that `RandomPoint` will select points on the region (the points are on surface of the region, excluding its interior).

```
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Tiny],Point[RandomPoint[\[ScriptCapitalR],5000]]},Boxed-> False]
```

[image: random points]

The region allows a way to find a random point on the surface of the region, or a point on the surface of the region nearest to a given point. For example,

```
RandomPoint[\[ScriptCapitalR]]
```

or to find the color nearest to RGB white,

```
RegionNearest[\[ScriptCapitalR],Level[ColorConvert[White,"LAB"],1]]
```

Again, because the `ChromaticityPlot3D` used the LAB color space, the points represent LAB colors. Here's a list of samples from the `ColorsNear` region. The colors from the random points are LAB colors; use `ColorConvert` to find the RGB values.

```
cols = LABColor @@@ RandomPoint[\[ScriptCapitalR], 10]
```

[image: random LAB colors]

```
ColorConvert[cols, "RGB"]
```

[image: random RGB colors]

Comment: you sir are genius.

Comment: Don't suppose its possible to return say the top 3 nearest from a target color?

Comment: I tried ```target = ColorConvert[RGBColor["#c468d7"], 
   "LAB"] // {#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} &;
near = RegionNearest[R];
n1 = near[target];
near[n1]``` but `n1` just returns itself.

Comment: You can use `Level[ColorConvert[RGBColor["#c468d7"],"LAB"],1]` to get the LAB components of the color. As it happens, `Level` works with any color, e.g., `Level[Red,1]==={1,0,0}`.